# Create Instance of a Class extending an Interface, passed through a Method?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, interface

I would like to pass an ArrayList of a class (i.e. Dog) that implements an interface (i.e. Animal) through a method, and I would like the method to create an instance of the given class.

I have tried many methods so far, but every resource I've found has told me how to do one part of the whole, yet combining those parts has been fruitless.

```
   private interface Animal {

    }

    private class Dog implements Animal {

    }

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

        doSomething(dogs);
    }

    public static <T extends Animal> void doSomething(ArrayList<T> list) {
        // This line does not compile or produces NoSuchMethodException based on how it's written:
        T newObj = new T().getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        list.add(newObj);
    }
```

In this example, would it be possible to pass an ArrayList of Dogs and expect `doSomething` method to add a Dog?

Comment: Not really.  You're much better off passing in `Dog::new` or some other `Supplier<T>`.

Comment: If you know the list won't be empty, and that the class of the first element has a constructor without parameters, you can do something like `list.get(0).getClass().newInstance()`

Answer (score 2):

Generics are erased at runtime, so given a method that just accepts a `List` object, **what you want is not possible at all**.

You have a second issue: You can't just 'make a `new T()`' even if somehow java had reified generics. What if the T type is abstract? What if T is an interface? What if T doesn't have a no-args constructor?

The solution is simple: Your method should accept not just the list, but also a thing that produces new Ts:

```
public static <T extends Animal> doSomething(List<T> list, Supplier<T> animalSupplier) {
  T newObj = animalSupplier.get();
  list.add(newObj);
}

// call like so:

List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
doSomething(dogs, Dog::new);
// or, if you find that easier to understand, this is identical:
doSomething(dogs, () -> new Dog());
```

You can't pass `new Dog()` - that would make a dog first, then pass the ref to this dog to the method. You don't want that - you want to pass the idea of 'how do I make a dog'. `Dog::new` turns into a `Supplier<Dog>` that operates by executing new Dog() every time you call `.get()` on that supplier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How would this solution work if I absolutely needed to construct the `Dog` in the `doSomething` method?  In my actual project, `doSomething` has data that is passed into the `Dog` constructor, meaning it would likely have to be instantiated inside the method.

Comment: Nope. There is no way in java to express in class form that there is to be a constructor with a certain property. Constructors live outside of the type system in that sense. There are 2 options: [A] doSomething will call some setters to set the properties. In which case, add those setters to the `interface Animal`, use the `Supplier` argument to make a new one, and then call those setters.

Comment: [B] There's a constructor that takes, say, a `String sound`, and you want `doSomething` to pass the value for this to the Dog constructor. In which case, replace `Supplier<T>` with `Function<String, T>` (where `T` is declared as `<T extends Animal>`). Use: `func.apply("bark");`, and `doSomething(list, s -> new Dog(s))`.